# php- errors when using html inside echo

Tags: php, html, apache, echo

I am using:

```
if (condition) {
    ..statements..
} else {
    echo '<div class="errormsgbox">'. $json->text.'</div>';
}
```

But I am getting the following error (I got this error after I restarted my web server, it was working fine before that):

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'errormsgbox' (T_STRING) in index.php on line 49
```

I don't think that I have put wrong syntax, what could be wrong?

Comment: Show the code around that line.

Comment: What is inside the `$json->text`, does it also contain `errormsgbox` somewhere?

Comment: @ziGi no it only contains a phone number.

Comment: @JohnConde i dont knowif my code  is wrong or what is wrong, it was working before i turned 'display_errors' on in php.ini and restarted apache

Comment: Sounds like you might have an unbalanced double quote (") inside ..statements.. that is matching the first " for the class, making errormsgbox and unexpected string.

Comment: Try to escape doublequotes \" and see if error still appears. If it does, you can try to put brackets around your string.